# Pyjnius. ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module was not found

Tags: java, python, pyjnius

I installed pyjnius and after importing I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
     from jnius import autoclass, cast
   File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\jnius\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
     from .jnius import *  # noqa
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module was not found.
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I installed java jdk on drive D. As soon as I reinstalled jdk on drive C (by standard) the error disappeared